# Recreate web analytic

Tags: web-analytics

Our web analytic broken for past few month. All of the sudden it started to show zero hit. We looked at every possible scenario and solutions from msdn and different blogs. Nothing helped.

So I am going to recreate the web analytic service. What will happen if I supply existing staging and reporting databases during provisioning. Will it keep existing DBS or it will overwrite the existing DBS to create brand new DBS with same name?

Comment: Have you reviewed your event/ULS logs for errors about the Analytics service?  I've experienced the same thing and it was always related to permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Becca:

Follow Maria Burton's reply with the link. It helped me before where my usage files weren't being saved on the web front ends.

Also, make sure on all sp servers under windows service the "SharePoint Trace" starts with local service account instead of domain account.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt have a problem if you apply the existing databases. However I would recommend creating the new analytics service as a new service instead of immediatley getting rid of the other. Add this service to the default services group and take the other one out. See if that works if not then it wasnt the service to begin with and it is something more.

Comment: okay recreated brand new web analytic with brand new databases but problem still there. I really need some tier 3 suggestion as to what to do next. Extremely under time crunch. Btw the new wa service is in default group and I took out the old wa svc.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have tried everything. Would you please run thru these steps?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2012/03/16/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2010-web-analytics.aspx